# call Jenkins api exception

Tags: ssl, jenkins

I am trying to call jenkins api by its restful url.

The url type of jenkins is https.

I always get below exception when I do that.

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match

Could somebody enlighten me how to fix this?

Comment: If you click on the bottom of the page, can you see the API output on your browser? This is step 1. For step 2, you need to provide an example of how you are trying to access Jenkins.

Comment: @Lovato I use httpclient to access jenkins

Comment: Have you tried python requests? I personally am using jenkins-webapi.